# Getting html output of selenium page with error while running wdio.conf.js with selenium standalone service and chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am getting Error followed by html code of selenium page when running tests from wdio with command wdio wdio.conf.js

package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "OpenWeathermap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Tests for Open WeatherMap application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "author": "Parth Vyas",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "selenium-standalone": "6.15.1",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "~0.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "~0.1",
    "wdio-cucumber-framework": "^2.2.8",
    "wdio-docker-service": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.43.3",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.5.0",
    "wdio-allure-reporter": "^0.6.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1"
  }
}
```

And wdio.conf.js looks like this

```
exports.config = {

    specs: [
        './tests/features/**/*.feature'
    ],
       exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],
     capabilities: [{
        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 2,
        //
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
        //args: ['--headless'],
        proxyType: 'MANUAL',
        httpProxy: 'http://localhost:4444/console'
        }

    }],
    path:'/',
    sync: true,
    logLevel: 'verbose',
    coloredLogs: true,
    deprecationWarnings: true,
    bail: 0,
    baseUrl: 'https://openweathermap.org',

    services: ['selenium-standalone'],
        seleniumArgs: {
      seleniumArgs: ["-port", "4444"],
      javaArgs: [
        "-Xmx1024m"
      ]
    },

    dockerLogs: './logs',
    dockerOptions: {
    image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome',
    healthCheck: 'http://localhost:4444',
    options: {
       p: ['4444:4444'],
       shmSize: '2g'
        }
      },

       framework: 'cucumber',
        cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['./tests/features/step-definitions'],        // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
        backtrace: false,   // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
        compiler: [],       // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
        dryRun: false,      // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
        failFast: false,    // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
        format: ['pretty'], // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
        colors: true,       // <boolean> disable colors in formatter output
        snippets: true,     // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
        source: true,       // <boolean> hide source uris
        profile: [],        // <string[]> (name) specify the profile to use
        strict: false,      // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
        tags: [],           // <string[]> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
        timeout: 20000,     // <number> timeout for step definitions
        ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false, // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
    },
```

Output on console : 
    C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\OpenWeathermap>wdio wdio.conf.js

```
[01:10:17]  COMMAND     POST     "/session"
[01:10:17]  DATA                {"desiredCapabilities":{"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"handlesAlerts":true,"rotatable":true,"maxInstances":2,"browserName":"c
hrome","chromeOptions":{"proxyType":"MANUAL","httpProxy":"http://localhost:4444/console"},"loggingPrefs":{"browser":"ALL","driver":"ALL"},"requestOrigins":{"url":"http://webdriver.io
","version":"4.14.0","name":"webdriverio"}}}
ERROR: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/displayhelpservlet.css" media="all"/>
  <link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/displayhelpservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = Object.freeze('{"consoleLink": "\u002fwd\u002fhub","type": "Standalone","class": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DisplayHelpHandler$DisplayHelpServletConfig","version": "
3.141.0"}');
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  <div id="help-heading">
    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>
    <h2>Selenium <span class="se-type"></span>&nbsp;v.<span class="se-version"></span></h2>
  </div>

  <div id="content-body">
    <p>
      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.
    </p>
    <p>
      For more information about Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> please see the
      <a class="se-docs">docs</a> and/or visit the <a class="se-wiki">wiki</a>.
      <span id="console-item">
        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> <a class="se-console">console</a>.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Happy Testing!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <footer id="help-footer">
      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from
      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our
      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
chrome
at new RuntimeError (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriverio\build\lib\utils\ErrorHandler.js:143:12)
at Request._callback (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriverio\build\lib\utils\RequestHandler.js:300:39)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriverio\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriverio\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriverio\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

set path in `wdio.conf.js` as path: `/wd/hub`

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users in the future if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).